# Как осуществить привязку ListBox к списку объекта класса?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Есть класс:

```
public class Project
{
    public ObservableCollection<String> Names { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<String>();
}
```

Есть вью-модель:

```
public class MainWindowVM
{
    public Project Project = new Project();

    public ObservableCollection<String> TestCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        Project.Names = new ObservableCollection<String>
        {
            "Name1",
            "Name2",
            "Name3",
            "Name4",
            "Name5"
        };

        TestCollection = Project.Names;
    }
}
```

И окно:

```
<Window x:Class="TestListBoxBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestListBoxBinding"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ListBox x:Name="ContactsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Project.Names}" Margin="5"/>   
</Window>
```

Почему не выводится список имен, хотя если ItemsSource установить значение {Binding Path=TestCollection}, то все работает, как нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding работает только со свойствами. В вашем примере `public Project Project` - поле.

Замените его на свойство:

```
public Project Project {get;set;}

public ObservableCollection<String> TestCollection { get; set; }

public MainWindowVM()
{
    Project = new Project();

    Project.Names = new ObservableCollection<String>
    {
        "Name1",
        "Name2",
        "Name3",
        "Name4",
        "Name5"
    };

    TestCollection = Project.Names;
}
```